# ng-click not working in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I have very simple scenario here.

```
<body>
<h1 nametag name="name" logsomthing="logsomthing()">Hello {{name}} <a href="#" ng-click="logsomthing()">Click here for alert</a></h1>
</body>
```

js

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('nametag', function() {

return {
    scope: {
      name: '=',
      logsomthing: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $attrs, $log) {
      $scope.name = 'John Doe';

      $scope.logsomthing = function() {
        alert('it is working');
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    }
  };
});
```

It should alert('it is working') on click but nothing happens. I can't find solution.

Here is http://plnkr.co/edit/QbcVynqzkIniYEpMD9mX?p=preview

Comment: Just remove the `scope` object in your directive return function and it should work just fine. No need to pass any `scope` because the scope/s are already in the directive itself.

Comment: <h1 nametag name="name" logsomthing="logsomthing()">Hello {{name}} <a href="#" ng-click="logsomthing()">Click here for alert</a></h1> This html is not in the scope of directive. So can not access the $scope.logsomthing this method. To achive this you need to specify the directive template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to work, you need to put a template inside your directive :

http://plnkr.co/edit/QXnDqDwQuyGhKpHZoCvy?p=preview

**directive :**

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('nametag', function() {

 return {
  scope: {
    name: '@',
  },
  template:'Hello {{name}} <a href="#" ng-click="logsomthing()">Click here for alert</a>',
  controller: function($scope, $attrs, $log) {
      //$scope.name = 'John Doe';    // Not necessary anymore, sent by the view

      $scope.logsomthing = function() {
        alert('it is working');
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    }
};
```

});

**View :**

```
<body>
  <h1 nametag name="John Doe"></h1>
</body>
```

And you also don't need to define 3 times you function logsomthing

Comment: Sorry, but he declared the `$scope.name` inside the directive itself so no need to pass the `name` scope.

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. Thx for spotting that. I updated my answer with the easiest way to share a name to a directive

Comment: Can i use ng-click like this ?

<h1 nametag name="name" ng-click="logsomthing()"></h1>